# Python Regular Expressions - How is "+?" equivalent to "*"

Tags: python, regex

```
   * : 0 or more occurrences of the pattern to its left
   + : 1 or more occurrences of the pattern to its left     
   ? : 0 or 1 occurrences of the pattern to its left
```

**How is "+?" equivalent to "*" ?**

Consider a search for any 3 letter word if it exists.

```
re1.search(r,'(\w\w\w)*,"abc")
```

In case of re1, * tries to get either 0 or more occurrences of the pattern to its left which in this case is the group of 3 letters. So it will either try to find a 3 letter word or fail

```
re2.search(r,'(\w\w\w)+?,"abc")
```

In case of re2, it's supposed to give the same output but I'm confused as to why "*" and "?+" are equivalent. Can you please explain this ?

Comment: The star means that it can occur zero or more times. The plus means it can occur one or more times. The question mark means it could occur or it could not occur. When you put the plus with the question mark you get a statement that is logically equivalent to the star.

Comment: Actually, a subtle point is that `+?` is a digraph that signifies a *reluctant qualifier*: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: Both are not same where the first one matches an empty string where the second one won't.

Comment: What do you mean by "supposed to give the same output"? Do you mean that you read an explanation somewhere saying they were equivalent? `(\w\w\w)` would also give the same output for your example, and it's clearly not equivalent, so I think we're missing part of your explanation of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` and `+?` are *not*  equivalent. The `?` takes on a special meaning if it follows a quantifier, making that quantifier *lazy*.

Usually, quantifiers are *greedy*, meaning they will try to match as many repetitions as they can; lazy quantifiers match as few as they can. But `a+?` will still match at least one `a`.

```
In [1]: re.search("(a*)(.*)", "aaaaaa").groups()
Out[1]: ('aaaaaa', '')

In [2]: re.search("(a+?)(.*)", "aaaaaa").groups()
Out[2]: ('a', 'aaaaa')
```

In your example, both regexes happen to match the same text because both `(\w\w\w)*` and `(\w\w\w)+?` can match three letters, and there are exactly three letters in your input. But they will differ in other strings:

```
In [12]: re.search(r"(\w\w\w)+?", "abcdef")
Out[12]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='abc'>

In [13]: re.search(r"(\w\w\w)+?", "ab") # No match

In [14]: re.search(r"(\w\w\w)*", "abcdef")
Out[14]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 6), match='abcdef'>

In [15]: re.search(r"(\w\w\w)*", "ab")
Out[15]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you run with a simpler expression you will see is not the same:

```
import re
>>> re.search("[0-9]*", "1")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='1'>
>>> re.search("[0-9]*", "")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
>>> re.search("[0-9]+", "")
>>> re.search("[0-9]+", "1")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='1'>
```

The problem in your code is (words)+?. is one or more or nothing